# Codeigniter problem with retriving value from database

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter, mysql, get

Alright Im trying to retrive the number of rows where members are individual and active.

Ive narrowed the problem to my model. Everything was working fine until I added a second clause to my get_where

Here is my model function

```
    function count_individual_active_members()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('Membership', array('Membership_Status' => 'Active', 'Membership_cat' => 'Individual'));
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

What and I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys,

fixed it on my own :D

```
 function count_individual_active_members()
 {
  $query = $this->db->where(array('Membership_Status' => 'Active', 'Membership_Cat' => 'Individual'));
  $query = $this->db->get('Membership');
  return $query->num_rows();
 }
```

Comment: Not sure what you did to troubleshoot and fix it, but it's usually helpful to use $this->db->last_query() to find out exactly what query was executed (so you can see what you screwed up).

Comment: Was it simply the column name was wrong? Membership_cat instead of Membership_Cat.  SQL is case sensitive for column names.